# How to use jQuery for future elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI date picker plugins for input class ".date-input".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".date-input").datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
      maxDate: "0",
      yearRange: "1990:2021",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    })
})
```

But the elements will be created in future by jQuery. How to achieve the desire result?

Comment: I think we need some more details.. What do you mean by "created in the future". Will you code them in the future, then I suggest you do that before writing this function.. If you mean they will be rendered after the page has been loaded, please tell us how they will be "created in the future".

Comment: For events, you can use delegated events.  In this case, you can either add your code *after* the element has been created or, once you've completely exhausted that option, you *could* use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: _"But the elements will be created in future"_ - Add the datepicker (`.datepicker({ ... })`) when you add the `.date-input` elements. Where's the problem with that?

Comment: @freedomn-m Even then there will most likely be events that are triggered when these elements are created or when they have been added to the DOM (Imho a `MutationObserver` should be the last resort)

Answer (score 1):

If you are making the datepicker elements yourself, you can do this: (i.e. make the datepicker and *then* set the options on it.)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="contents"></div>
<script>

    // make the date picker
    $('#contents').append('<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>');
    
    // set the datepicker options
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
       dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
       maxDate: "0",
       yearRange: "1990:2021",
       changeMonth: true,
       changeYear: true
    });     

</script> 
</body>
</html>
```